# SQL query- ID not exist in another table or exist but with all records are in history?

Tags: sql, select, db2

i have table T1

```
ID
1
2
3
```

and table T2

```
ID    HISTORY
1       1
1       1
2       1
2       0
```

I must select from T1 all records which does not exist in T2 or exists but all records are in history (history flag =1)

So for this my result will be

```
1
3
```

What is the correct SQL query for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try this:

```
select * from T1
where ID not in(select ID from T2 where HISTORY_FLG!=1)
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1169b/1)

Comment: I cant use this because select id from T2 where h!=1 will return  and "2"

Comment: @Dejan:but that is inside the subquery rt? Please check the demo

Comment: you think it will not return "2"?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `not exists`

```
select * 
from t1 t
where not exists
     (
       select 1
       from t2 a
       where a.id = t.id
       and a.HISTORY <> 1
     )
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b79e/1/0) DEMO

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * from T1 
WHERE id not 
IN ( SELECT tb1.id FROM( SELECT id FROM T2 WHERE history=0 ) as tb1 )
```